# error: parse error on input ‘where’

Tags: haskell, ghc

Struggling to understand the GHC compiler and it's mysterious indentation rules but unfortunately this block of code refuses to compile

Sorry I know this question has been asked before but just can't get this code to compile

```
fib :: Int -> [Int] 
fib 1 = [1]
fib 2 = [1,1]
fib n =
   if n > 1
     then 
         reverse list 
          where
           list = ((head (fib (n-1)) + head (fib (n-2))) : fib (n-1))
    else
        error "Exception, n cannot be less than 0"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with indentation, `where` is just not allowed here by the syntax. Normally you use `where` in bindings (`a = b where c`) whereas `then`-clause requires an expression. Use `let...in`.

Comment: @n.m.You should make that as an answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it isn't *GHC* that makes the indentation rules, it's the Haskell language specification...

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of indentation, `where` is not allowed at this syntactic position.

Normally the `where` clause is allowed in *bindings* that look like `a = b where c`. Formally, according to the [language report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-830004.4.3), `where` is a part of *rhs* (which stands for "right-hand side (of a declaration/binding)", and *rhs* is defined like this:

> *rhs* → = *exp* [**where** *decls*]
>           | *gdrhs* [**where** *decls*]

and *gdrhs* is the guarded right-hand side which is defined as

> *gdrhs* → *guards* = *exp* [*gdrhs*]

So `where` can only be used when using `=`, that is, making a binding.

(There are other kinds of `where` clauses: in a module, in class/instance definitions, in GADT definitions, but those are only tangentially related).

In an expression, use `let ... in`:

```
let list = ((head (fib (n-1)) + head (fib (n-2))) : fib (n-1))
in  reverse list
```

or just straight

```
reverse ((head (fib (n-1)) + head (fib (n-2))) : fib (n-1))
```